# Interpreter Function

Tags: functions

I want to create a FormFunction that takes arbitrary many integer numbers and calculates the average. You want to use only one input field, but for more convenince allow users to write their numbers in different formats:

1. input1: "1; 2; 3; 4; 5 "
2. input2: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5 "
3. input3: "1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5 "
4. input4: "1, 2; 3/ 4 5 "

All inputs should yield 3 as the output of the FormFunction (after the input has been submitted). I want to use Interpreter to process these different types of input.
Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `StringReplace`to transform the different inputs into WL. The only problematic case is when two numbers are only separated by a space, but we can treat this by using a regular expression.

```
mean[in_String] := Module[{st = in},
  st = StringReplace[st, {";" -> ",", "/" -> ",", 
     RegularExpression["(\\d) (\\d)"] -> "$1,$2"}];
  st = "{" <> st <> "}";
  Mean[ToExpression[st]]
  ]
mean["1; 2; 3; 4; 5 "]
mean["1, 2, 3, 4, 5 "]
mean["1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5 "]
mean["1, 2; 3/ 4 5 "]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is pretty cool, Daniel. But it doesn't really answer the question, since he wants to create a FormFunction. Do you know how to elaborate from here?

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part is the number extraction:

```
extract[s_String] := 
  ToExpression /@ StringSplit[s, (" " | "," | ";" | "/") ..]

extract /@ {"1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ",
            "1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ",
            "1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5 ",
            "1, 2; 3/ 4 5 "}

(*    {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
       {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
       {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
       {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}    *)
```

Define a [`FormFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) using the above `extract` and a call to [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html):

```
form = FormFunction["input" -> "String", 
                    Mean[extract["input" /. #]] &];
```

activate it with

```
form[]
```

and see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

that tasks seems like a tough one. As in the previous solutions mentioned, the hard part for me was adding a space a separator but eventually I tried RegularExpression[].
However, I am not sure how to implement my idea in the function Interpreter[] as it is needed by your request.